# Another exercises of measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Here another exercises of measure theory:

Let $(E,d)$ metric space, and $\mathbb{P}$ probability measure over $(E,B(E))$ . Prove that $\mathbb{P}$ is regular, i.e. if $A \in B(E)$ and $\epsilon>0$ then exists $F,G$ closed and open (respectively) set such that $F \subset A \subset G$ and $\mathbb{P}(G-F)<\epsilon$

Comment: Please, look at section 2 and specially Proposition 2.3 of the [notes](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/jancol1.pdf). There you will find a detailed proof .

Answer (score 0):

The following proof is adapted from Theorem $1.1$ of *Convergence of Probability Measures* by Patrick Billingsley:

Let $d(x, A)$ be the distance function from $x$ to $A$, i.e., 
$$d(x, A) = \inf_{y \in A}d(x, y).$$

If $A$ is closed, we can take $F = A$ and $G = A^\delta = \{x: d(x, A) < \delta\}$ for some $\delta$, since $A^\delta$ is open and decreases to $A$ as $\delta \downarrow 0$.

Denote by $\mathscr{G}$ the class of sets in $\mathscr{B}(E)$ with the asserted property (frequently used arguments in measure theory). It can be shown that $\mathscr{G}$ is a $\sigma$-field (details left) that contains the class of closed sets. Since $\mathscr{B}(E)$ is generated by the class of closed sets, we conclude $\mathscr{G} = \mathscr{B}(E)$ and the proof is complete.